# Given $X^*$ with the quotient topology is homeomorphic to the circle $S^1$ with the subspace topology from $R^2$.

Tags: general-topology

Say I have $X = [0,1]$.

Say $X^*$ is the partition of $X$ such that $X^*$ is made up of the single-point sets $\{x\}$ for $x\in (0,1)$ and the double-point set $D =\{0,1\}$.

I'm trying to prove that $X^*$ with the quotient topology is homeomorphic to the circle $S^1$ with the subspace topology from $R^2$.

I have a general definition of the quotient topology as "the finest topology that makes the projection map continuous." Accordingly, the quotient space we're working with is the space obtained by taking the quotient set of the original topological space with the quotient topology as defined above.

I'm also aware that a homeomorphism is the mapping that preserves all the topological properties of a given space. To disprove a homeomorphism, I normally tackle the problem by identifying some property not present in one of the two things being compared.

For proving that a homeomorphism is present in this particular example, I'm a bit confused.

I know $[0,1]$ is compact and believe $S^1$ in $R^2$ is also. I'm clearly missing something critical though.

Does anyone have thoughts on this proof?

Comment: To prove two spaces $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic you need to construct a bijection $\phi:X\to Y$ such that both $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ are continuous. Continuous maps out of quotients work nicely; your characterization of the quotient topology helps a lot. There is a standard trick (that I don't know whether you've seen) for the other direction.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the trick you're talking about.